# ASP.NET DetailsView EmptyDataTemplate button handler

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I put a `button` in the `EmptyDataTemplate` of a `DetailsView`. If I double-click it it will set a handler for me in the code-behind.

Is there a way to setup the handler without having to double-click the button in the designer.

In the code-behind I don't have access to the button id for me to attach a handler to it?

So I manually put `OnClick="btnNew_Click"` attribute in the markup. Is there a way to do this in the code-behind?

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3" Height="50px" Width="50%">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNewNote" OnClick="btnNew_Click" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="New" Text="New"></asp:LinkButton>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can call the code that is inside `btnNew_Click` from any other method or the Page_Load. Also the DetailsView has all sorts of events you can use. Start typing "on" in the DetailsView aspx and you'll see what is available.

Comment: In the code-behind in OnInit event, I'm used to saying btnSave.Click+=btnSave_Clicked; But I don't have access to the button that exists in the EmptyDataTemplate in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FindContol` to locate the LinkButton in the `EmptyDataTemplate` and add a Click event.

```
LinkButton lb = DetailsView2.FindControl("lnkNewNote") as LinkButton;
lb.Click += btnNew_Click;
```